# What is "hostilities" in the context of the Military Commissions Act of 2006?

Tags: united-states, military

According to the [Military Commissions Act of 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Commissions_Act_of_2006):

> The term 'unlawful enemy combatant' means —
> (i) a person who has engaged in **hostilities** or who has purposefully and materially supported **hostilities** against the United States

What exactly does "hostilities" mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act does not define  "hostilities", which means that its ordinary and usual meaning should be understood. Also, the act several times uses  "hostilities" in connection with the term "combat", and once to describe the actions of a "terrorist group".

It would seem then that "armed combat or terrorism"  would be a good definition for  "hostilities" in this act.